# Como enviar los datos de un formulario a GMAIL con PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, gmail

Necesito saber como puedo enviar los valores que el usuario rellene en un formulario de contacto, mediante PHP hacia un correo electronico

Answer (score 2):

creo que esto puede ser tu solución:

En primer lugar, necesitarás un formulario, por ejemplo este, que podrás tener en tu archivo "contacto.html" (Por ejemplo)

```
<form method="POST" action="enviar.php">
    <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    <input type="text" name="telefono" placeholder="Telefono">
    <textarea name="Mensaje" placeholder="Tu mensaje aqui"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Ahora en la misma carpeta, crea un archivo que se llame:
enviar.php (según hemos llamado en el action del form) que contenga estos datos:

```
<?php

// Declaración de variables del formulario
$nombre = $_POST['Nombre'];
$email = $_POST['Email'];
$telefono = $_POST['Telefono'];
$mensaje = $_POST['Mensaje'];

// Datos del email
$para = $email;
$titulo = 'S&S Solicitud de presupuesto';
$header = 'From: ' . $email;
$msjCorreo = "Nombre: $nombre\n Telefono: $telefono\n E-Mail: $email\n Mensaje:\n $mensaje";

if ($_POST['submit']) {

    if (mail($para, $titulo, $msjCorreo, $header)) {

    echo "<script language='javascript'>
    alert('Mensaje enviado, muchas gracias por contactar con nosotros.');
    </script>";
    } else {
        echo 'Falló el envio';
    }
}

?>
```

En $para , puedes poner tu email así:

$para = 'tuemail@hola.com';

O dejar la variable email, para que le llegue al usuario una copia.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! Me funciono correctamente!

Comment: Me alegro!! suerte en tu proyecto :)

Comment: Hice todo tal cual pero sale: "Falló el envio" y en gmail no llega nada. ¿ ¿Qué podrá ser?

Comment: Hola @MoisesHurtado, podría poner una respuesta con su código? así voy un poco a ciegas para saber lo que puede ocurrir.